# javascript validation does not work as intended

Tags: javascript, jsp, spring-mvc

i'm doing some validation and I don't understand why it is not working.

what i'm trying to do is a search with two radio buttons with text field. if one selected and the text field is empty i try to throw a alert!

with my code its not even run the javascript

here is my script

```
function validater() {
    with(document) {

        if (document.getElementById("textch").value == "") {
            alert("Please enter Child Id Or Name");

        }
        return false;

    }
}
```

and here is the  jsp code:

```
<form:form commandName="searchdetails" action="viewChild" id="childsearch" method="post" onSubmit="return validater();">



<td height="56" colspan="3">
<div align="center">
<form:radiobutton path="fieldvalue" value="childid" id="type"  onClick="Selecttype('selecttypechild?','childid')"/>
  Child ID
 <form:radiobutton path="fieldvalue" value="name" id="type" onClick="Selecttype('selecttypechild?','name');"/>
  Name  
  <form:radiobutton path="fieldvalue" value="dob" id="type" onClick="Selecttype('selecttypechild?','dob')"/>
   DOB  
    <form:radiobutton path="fieldvalue" value="admit" id="type" onClick="Selecttype('selecttypechild?','admit')"/>
    Admit period  
   </div></td>


 <div id="chname" > 
  <c:if test="${empty stype}">
  <form:input   path="textvalue" placeholder="Type here" id="textch"/>
  </c:if>
<c:if test="${stype eq 'textbox'}">
<form:input  type="text" path="textvalue" placeholder="Type here" id="textcha"/>
  </c:if>

<input id="submit" type="submit" value="Go">
```

Comment: Show your generated HTML, not your server side code.

Comment: Protip: The best JavaScript is no JavaScript. `<input ... required />`. Problem solved.

Comment: remove `with(document)`

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Did OP say he's working with HTML5?

Comment: @Quentin i dont get it.. what else you want?
i posted the all codes needed 
what i need is if i click the submit button without enter anything it should run the script.

Comment: @GobyDot — HTML instead of whatever `<form:input` and `<c:if` are.

Comment: @Quentin i post the code

Comment: @GobyDot — You've posted more of the server side code but still none of the HTML that the browser actually receives.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is invalid. You cannot have a `<td>` as a child element of a `<form>`.

When browsers error recover from elements being placed in parts of a table where they are not allowed, they often place those elements *after* the table.

This results in your form being outside the table but your inputs being inside the table.

Since the submit button isn't inside the form, it won't submit the form. Since it won't submit the form, it won't trigger the submit event and won't run the JS.

The only ways that you can nest forms and tables are to have the form entirely with in a table cell or an entire table within a form.

Use [a validator](http://validator.w3.org). Write valid HTML.

(And avoid using tables for layout).

Answer (score -1):

Try this without `with(document)` and `value === ""` instead of `value == ""`

```
function validater() {
    if (document.getElementById("textch").value === "") {
        alert("Please enter Child Id Or Name");
    }
    return false;
}
```

or you can simply use [Html5 Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp)

```
<input type="text" id="textch" required>
```